# Error WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application with gdal - GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, gdal, geodjango

I've installed `GEODjango` with `gdal` on Windows. But i've got an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "g
dal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

After that, I've configured `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` by inserting this line to `setting.py`:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\FeedGit\env\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py'
```

And got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FeedGit\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 49, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I think this is a mistake between Windows x64 and Windows x32. This is my python version:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

My computer is running Windows 7 64bit.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: In should be dll file can you try command `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = “C:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdalxxx.dll”` , please replace `xxx` with correct installed version e.g. `202`

Comment: I have 2 file in C:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdalxxx.dll" is : gdal111.dll and gdal202.dll. When I set GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = “C:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdal111.dll” it got this error: WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found. gdall202.dll got this error too.!

Comment: add `import ctypes` and `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(rC:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdal202.dll")` in your code on the top or add directory `C:/OSGeo4W/bin/` to environment path

Comment: Not work, @MaheshKaria

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: have you tried after adding it into environment path ?

Comment: I added it into enviroment path. I use OSGeo4W 64bit. Is it the reason for this error?

Comment: possibly because mostly people uses 32 bit python

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Install **OSGeo4W 32bit** and config:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal202.dll'
```

in **settings.py**. Thanks for @MaheshKaria